# How to convert the percentage system to the five-point scale using huffman tree?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, huffman-code

I am learning huffman tree these days and I have seen an example in some blogs and tutorials:

> Convert the percentage system to the five-point scale,which requires
>   the time performance of the algorithm is as high as possible.Assume
>   that the distribution of the student’s scores are as follows:
>   Score:  0～59  60～69  70～79  80～89  90～100   Ratio:  0.05   0.15
>   0.40    0.30    0.10

And then they generated a decision tree using huffman like this:
[decision tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyQmk.png)

But I think the huffman tree should be like this:
[huffman tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGLAC.png)

And I acknowledge that the decision tree is the right answer but I want to know how to generate it.

Thanks very much!

Comment: There are multiple ways to generate an "optimal" tree depending on what "optimal" actually means. It's not possible to answer your question without knowing the precise criterion of optimum. .

Comment: Sorry for my negligence. The problem requires the time performance of the algorithm is as high as possible. That is when the student's scores distribute as above-mentioned percentage, how to designe the desicion tree is optimal? And my question is how that desicion tree generate.